# how to load csv file data into table storage of azure datalake using data factory

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

how to load csv file data into table storage of azure data-lake using data factory.

Lets say i have a file with few columns and few rows and i want to upload this data into azure table storage of azure data-lake gen-2 using data factory.

I used copy activity of azure data factory and a file in the container of azure data-lake as source but for sink i couldn't see the option of selecting azure data-lake table storage.

Can you please let me know if i am missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

On the sink side you need to look for sink dataset as  "Azure Table Storage" and then you can navigate that from the UI itself .

Comment: Can we do insert or update (kind of sql merge) in azure table storage?